# I can`t connect MQTT HiveMQ

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mqtt, hivemq

I have a react app that I need to connect to control an ESP32. The first thing I thought was to use MQTT (HiveMQ) to communicate with the ESP. The problem is that an error is being returned in loop in my browser console

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://79642a966da549118f1128bb058d42ce.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud:8883/' failed:
```

If anyone knows what is happening or has any better solution to communicate with the ESP32 using JS it would be incredible too. Follow my index.tsx file

```
    export default function Home() {
    const options = {
        username: 'gio.nacimento',
        password: 'Gio133ebu',
    };

    const mqtt = require('mqtt');

// connect to your cluster, insert your host name and port
    const client = mqtt.connect('tls://79642a966da549118f1128bb058d42ce.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud:8883', options);

// prints a received message
    client.on('message', function(topic: any, message: any) {
        console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, message)); // need to convert the byte array to string
    });

// reassurance that the connection worked
    client.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected!');
    });

// prints an error message
    client.on('error', (error: any) => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    });

// subscribe and publish to the same topic
    client.subscribe('messages');
    client.publish('messages', 'Hello, this message was received from the app!');

    const test = (): void =>{
        client.subscribe('messages');
        client.publish('messages', 'Hello, this message was received from the app by clicking!');
    }

    return (
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center flex-col'>
            <h1>Controle de LED</h1>
            <button onClick={test}>Test server</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Don't  know if this can be a problem but I'm using React + Next in my app. I already follow all the instructions at HiveMq site but the error persists.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and errors (test in general). Please post them directly as text into the question.

Comment: I [believe Hive MQ](http://www.mqtt-dashboard.com/) listens for TLS websocket connections on port 8884 (not 8883 as shown in screenshot). You may also need `wss://`.

Comment: Browser based applications can ONLY connect to a MQTT broker using WebSockets or Secure WebSockets

Comment: You have also posted your credentials and URL for your broker in the image ( which can't be edited to remove them unlike if you had posted the text). Please make sure you change them as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank everyone for the advice. I just changed all images to written code :D

Comment: Try `wss://79642a966da549118f1128bb058d42ce.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud:8884/mqtt` (and please change your HiveMQ password! it's included in your question as mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by some other members, the WebSocket port in the HiveMQ Cloud broker is 8884, which is different from the usual MQTT (TLS) port of 8883 (1). Depending on your library, you may need to use the prefix wss:// or omit the prefix completely when connecting to HiveMQ Cloud's WebSocket port.

If you have any further questions or concerns, I would recommend visiting the HiveMQ Community Forum (2). Our community members and HiveMQ experts are always happy to help with any questions related to HiveMQ.

References:

1. HiveMQ Cloud Documentation. "WebSocket and MQTT ports." HiveMQ Cloud. Retrieved from https://www.hivemq.com/docs/cloud/enterprise/introduction/limits/#websocket-and-mqtt-ports
2. HiveMQ Community Forum. Retrieved from https://community.hivemq.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).